# Is using bindParam() better than using variables in PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to know is it ok to use variables in **mysql** functions inside **php**? While ofcourse making sure that the variables values not being received directly from client inputs.

For example is it better to use one of those queries on the other?

```
$stat = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`col1`, `col2`, `image`) 
VALUES ('$val1', '$val2')");
```

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`col1`, `col2`) 
VALUES (:val1, :val2)");

$stmt->bindParam('col1',$val1);
$stmt->bindParam('col2',$val2);
```

Comment: Always always always use parameters. See the SQL injection article in the bue box above. Even if input isn't coming directly from a user, it's still potentially a risk (unless perhaps you literally hard-coded the variable values into your PHP application code). And as well as injection problems, parameterisation also protects you from potential silly unexpected syntax errors due to the content of the input. e.g. a simple `'` in one of the values would break the SQL formatting in your first example. And parameters are easy to use, so there's simply no reason not to use them.

Comment: *Never* use variables like in the first example.

Comment: How do you know that a variable is "not being received directly from client inputs"? How do you know that a variable does not contain some special character?

Comment: If you're trying to avoid extra code you can pass all bindings in the `execute` function. `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table(\`col1\`, \`col2\`) 
VALUES (:val1, :val2)"); $stmt->execute(array(':val1' => $val1,  ':val2' => $val2));`

Comment: @YourCommonSense That I would for example sanitize the input and re check it's values etc before placing it in the query

Comment: @user3783243 would that still apply more indirect inserting like bindParam?

Comment: `I would for example sanitize the input and re check it's values etc before placing it in the query`...but the only way to fully "sanitise" against SQL injection is to use prepared statements and parameters. It's not clear precisely what you're proposing with that description, but basically no other known methods are sufficient, they will all have flaws (or worse, be completely irrelevant to the problem, which is what we commonly see when people suggest such things here. There is a lot of really bad advice out there on blogs and forums, sadly).

Comment: @Alsakka By `indirect inserting` do you mean binding? Yes, that would be the same as binding but less lines because you dont need a `bind*(` call for each value/param. You should not sanitize.

Comment: 1. What do you mean "sanitize"? Are you sure your "sanitization" is 100% safe? 2. Why?

Comment: @Alsakka `would that apply more indirect inserting`...yes. You can [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) to know this.

Comment: Yes, like you guys guessed it I followed some steps to make sure "in this case I have now which is to insert name, number into table" to make sure the variable only contains letters for name and number for **number** with **regex** for example plus removing any slashes etc on input.
And Thanks for clarifying that this works as binding!

Comment: Yeah...that's simply input format validation according to your business rules, not SQL injection santisation. We could not be sure it would prevent all forms of SQL attack. Just use parameters and then you don't need to worry about it, the problem is already solved for you :-)